# Multiprocessing program not giving desired output

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, fork

I have this multiprocess program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t i = fork();
    if(i == 0)
    {
        execv("./prcs1", (char *[]){ "./prcs1", argv[1], NULL});
        _exit(1);
    }
    else if (i > 0)
    {
        execv("./prcs2", (char *[]){ "./prcs2", argv[0], NULL});
        _exit(2);
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Fork failed");
        _exit(3);
    }
}
```

In this program `./prcs1` and `./prcs2` are the two executables of two different programs. `./prcs1` gives the output as `Syscall finished` and `./prcs2` gives the output `Stdlibrary finished`. And I am getting the following output in each run:

```
Syscall finished
Stdlibrary finished
```

Now, my questions are:

1. Does the above program run the two processes `prcs1` and `prcs2` in parallel?
2. If it does run in parallel, then will I be getting the same result each time, or could I also get an output where `Stdlibrary finished` comes first and `Syscall finished` comes second? If this can be possible, then why am I getting the same output in each run?

Comment: How much time do these take to execute? If, for example, `Syscall` is much faster than `Stdlibrary`, then you will get the same result pretty much always.

Comment: @VHarisop When I run the two programs separately using time, I get: real 0m0.044s, user 0m0.000s, sys 0m0.041s for the Syscall program, and real 0m0.028s, user 0m0.019s, sys 0m0.001s for the Stdlibrary process. So, looking at these time, will the result be same always?

Comment: No, they seem pretty comparable. You should look into Joachim's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you *create* a process with the `fork` function. After a successful `fork` call you will have two processes running in "parallel".

However, you have no influence over the process scheduler, so first of all you will not know which process will be the first to run, and unless you know how long each program you execute takes, then you can't predict how long each will run either. If all the two external programs (`prcs1` and `prcs2`) does is print a line to standard output, you can't say with certainty which line will be printed first.

Actually, if the operating systems process scheduler decides to switch process in the middle of the printing, the output can become garbled as both processes output becomes mixed with each other.

Comment: When I run the two programs separately using time, I get: real 0m0.044s, user 0m0.000s, sys 0m0.041s for the Syscall program, and real 0m0.028s, user 0m0.019s, sys 0m0.001s for the Stdlibrary process. So, looking at these time, will the result be same always?

Comment: @LindaNu As the OP said, this depends on the operating systems process scheduler.  This means that it could also depend on what else is running at the same time on your computer and the resources that they are using.

Comment: @Degustaf: All right, I guess I understand. As I analyzed the outputs with some more print statements, I saw that it does start executing with the Stdlibrary process, printing some of its outputs and then starts with the Syscall process, printing some of its outputs and does this parallely; the Syscall is finishing before and Stdlibrary one after that, even though it began before.